# Query for Namespace Projects via GitLab API

Tags: gitlab

I would like to query the GitLab API for projects contained within a namespace. From the API documentation it looks like there is not a way to do this. Anyone have a workaround?

I am using:

```
https://gitlab/api/v3/projects/all?private_token={private_token}
```

and tried using the search parameter but it seems that is just for project names. I suppose I could put a prefix or suffix on each project name but I really don't want to. The projects API documentation is located @ https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/projects.md

If it is not possible maybe a feature request is in order?

Answer (score 2):

For gitLab API V4 try this `http://gitlab.yourOrg.com/api/v4/groups/your_namespace/projects?per_page=100&page=1&private_token={private_token}`

It seems that you are leaving out the Groups (namespace) part from the URL.

Comment: Nice to see they added support. Thanks! I'll refactor when I have the chance to use this.